# Ignore property setting the default value during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class

```
public class MyClass{
    public string MyFirstProperty { get; set; } = "Hello";
    public string MySecondProperty { get; set; } = "There";
}
```

I then call a method with this class being instantiated as the parameter

```
var result = MyMethod(new MyClass());
```

When I am debugging and press `F11` in order to step into the method, it actually steps into the class instantiation of setting these properties. Is there any setting in Visual Studio that allows me to auto skip this?

In Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General, I already have `Step over property evaluation and other implicit function calls`set to true and `Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls` set to false.

Comment: Have you tried to hit F10 (step over) instead of F11 (step into)?

Comment: I always do next way: click `F11` -> it goes into `MyClass` properties, next click `Shift+F11` -> it skips property initialization, next click `F11` -> go to `MyMethod` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just hitting <kbd>F10</kbd> that is for steeping over instead of <kbd>F11</kbd> that is used for stepping into.

[Step Into, Step Over, Step Out Commands (Debug Menu)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/step-into-step-over-step-out-commands-debug-menu)

Or you can use <kbd>F11</kbd> => <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> => <kbd>F11</kbd> as @Alex also suggested.